Gitea hook pre-receive
I have a problem pushing changes to my git repo on Gitea 1.22.3 running in docker on TrueNAS. I get following error response. I've cross-checked all settings and searched for help on StackOverflow and other sources. None helped.
The "problem" is caused by pre-commit hook git/repositories/user/somerepo/hooks/pre-receive.d/gitea, when I remove this file and no pre-commit hook gets executed, push works.
remote: Gitea: Internal Server Error Decoding Failed        
remote: Gitea: HookPreReceive(last) failed: unable to decode error response "POST https://localhost:44880/api/internal/hook/pre-receive/user/somerepo": readObjectStart: expect { or n, but found <, error found in #2 byte of ...|        
remote: <!DOCTYPE h|..., bigger context ...|        
remote: <!DOCTYPE html>        
remote: <html lang="en-US" data-theme="gite|...        

I use HTTPS (with TrueNAS certificate)
.
It's same if I use http (no certificate). gitea doctor says everything is ok
gitea-788cb9d4d7-4k9f4:/var/lib/gitea$ gitea doctor check

[1] Check paths and basic configuration
 - [I] Configuration File Path:    "/etc/gitea/app.ini"
 - [I] Repository Root Path:       "/var/lib/gitea/git/repositories"
 - [I] Data Root Path:             "/var/lib/gitea"
 - [I] Custom File Root Path:      "/var/lib/gitea/custom"
 - [I] Work directory:             "/var/lib/gitea"
 - [I] Log Root Path:              "/var/lib/gitea/data/log"
OK

[2] Check Database Version
 - [I] Expected database version: 299
OK

[3] Check if user with wrong type exist
OK

[4] Check if OpenSSH authorized_keys file is up-to-date
OK

[5] Synchronize repo HEADs
 - [I] All 104 repos have their HEADs in the correct state
OK

All done (checks: 5).

